# Why would one use a Hann or Bartlett window?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, window-functions, finite-impulse-response

Suppose we're designing a low-pass FIR filter, and I want to use one of these three windows: Bartlett, Hann or Hamming. From Oppenheim & Schafer's *Discrete-Time Signal Processing, 2nd Ed*, p. 471:}

> [image]

All three of them provide the same transition band width: $$\Delta\omega=\frac{8\pi}{N}$$ where $N$ is the order of the filter and is assumed large enough.

However, the overshoot (let's call it $\delta$) is different for each window, an the following inequality holds:

$$\delta_{Hamming}<\delta_{Hann}<\delta_{Bartlett}$$

So if we use a Hamming window, we get the smallest overshoot and a transition band with width $\Delta\omega$. If we use one of the other two windows, the width of the transition band is the same, but the overshoot increases.

This leads me to think that there is no case in which one would use a Hann or a Bartlett window, as the Hamming one is better than them: it improves one aspect ($\delta$), stays the same in another ($\Delta\omega$).

The question is: why would someone choose a Hann or a Bartlett window if a Hamming one can always be used?

Comment: Could you provide some clarification - do you have references for those equations? What do you mean by "overshoot" in this context?

Comment: @MartinThompson I just added the reference. By overshoot I mean the peak of the frequency response due to the discontinuity of the ideal low-pass filter that one tries to approximate to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In reviewing fred harris' Figures of Merit for various windows (Table 1 in this [link](https://doi.org/10.1109/proc.1978.10837)) the Hamming is compared to the Hanning (Hann) at various values of $\alpha$ and from that it is clear that the Hann would provide greater stopband rejection (The classic Hann is with $\alpha =2$ and from the table the side-lobe fall-off is -18 dB per octave). I provided the link as you can see many more considerations involved when choosing a window for various applications.

The result of this is apparent when comparing the kernels for a 51 sample Hann and Hamming window using Matlab/Octave. Note the higher first sidelobe level with Hann but significantly greater rejection overall:

[image: Kernels]

So bottom line, what I think was missing from the OP's table of reference but an important consideration is the rate of side-lobe roll-off. This is of particular concern with multisampling applications since there can be many alias bands that fold-in, so a rapid roll-off helps minimize noise growth. Also in the interest of minimizing overall noise in the presence of AWGN (only) a faster roll-off at the expense of a higher first lobe could be preferred.

**Additional Notes of Related Interest:**

Personally, I would not use either window for filter design. If any window, I would use the Kaiser or DPSS windows, or instead of windowing design the FIR filter with the least squares algorithm (`firls` in Matlab, Octave and Python's scipy.signal). See [FIR Filter Design: Window vs Parks McClellan and Least Squares](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37704/fir-filter-design-window-vs-parks-mcclellan-and-least-squares) for the related discussion.

I convolved a 26 sample Hann with a 26 Hamming to come up with an alternate 51 sample "Hann-Hamming" with the following result (note the label is incorrect in the graphic, this should be "Hann-Hamming" not "Hann-Hanning"):

[image: comparative plot Hann-Hamming, Hann, Hamming]

**UPDATE:** This Hann-Hamming does not (generally) out-perform a Kaiser window of similar main-lobe width:

[image: Hann-Hamming vs Kaiser]

I then tried what I call a "SuperKaiser" where I convolved two shorter length Kaiser windows to come up with an alternate 51 tap window with the following result. This was done by convolving Kaiser(26,5.5) with Kaiser(26,5.5) such that SuperKaiser(51,5.5)= conv(kaiser(26,5.5),kaiser(26,5.5)). At first glance it appears to generally outperform the kaiser(51,12), matching the main lobe width and providing superior stopband rejection over most of the stopband. An integration of total stopband noise under the assumption of AWGN is of interest to see if this new window is superior under that condition (does the relative area under the first two sidelobes where SuperKaiser is inferior completely offset all the remaining stopband improvement?). If I have time I will add that assessment. Interesting! As @A Concerned Citizen astutely pointed out, as we keep convolving we should approach a Gaussian window.

[image: SuperKaiser]

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer. That table has something that looks weird to me. I believed that the Hann window was [defined univocally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function). In that paper, it appears that it has a variable parameter $\alpha$. Where does it come from? If we vary $\alpha$, is the window still a Hann function strictly speaking?

Comment: @Tendero fred harris explains in detail on page 181 in the link section C for the $Cos^{\alpha}(X)$ windows, and there he says the Hann window specifically is with $\alpha =2$.  I made that clearer in the answer, thanks!

Comment: That intriguing comparison made me repeat it, but I couldn't get the same results. Then I took a closer look and it looks like you didn't closely match Kaiser's parameter. Using the `As` design, I got very close with `As=108.5` for `N=32` and `N[hann]=17`, `N[ham]=16`, but the sidelobes of the convolved window are unequal and they wobble above Kaiser's. I've seen people "mingling" two windows, or more, but either as arithmetic or geometric mean, never convolved. Still, the results are impressive.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes something was not right about that and indeed was me using too quickly 30 and 31 to create an "equivalent" 51 tap window: What I was doing was comparing a 60 sample window to a 51 tap Kaiser- Not fair! I updated the post by convolving 26 and 26 which results in 51 samples which would then be a fair comparison, and of course Kaiser appears to win for overall performance (although I did not go through an integrate total stopband noise). Convolving seems a natural choice as it results in multiplying the frequency responses, equivalent to cascading two windows.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen This prompted me to try convolving two Kaisers with a very interesting result. If the overall noise performance under AWGN conditions is better, then of further interest would be to convolve four Kaiser's etc perhaps ultimately illuminating a new window that is bult up from the convolution of a 2 sample base-function? What we do see as expected from the convolution is a faster stopband roll-off at the expense of higher close-in side-lobes. This is not unlike the $\alpha$ first mentioned for the expanded Hann functions, so likely nothing new- but still interesting to me.

Comment: DPSS comes to mind now. Just thought I'd light the fuse a bit... :-) Still, the results, now that I look a bit more to your graphs, seem to converge, naturally, towards the Gaussian way. After all, even `n` rectangular "windows" (let's call them that), convolved enough times, will give a Gaussian, so the high frequency attenuation should be increased at the cost of widened central lobe. I guess after 100 convolutions of Kaiser, the overall imaginary anvelope would come close to a Gaussian of... whatever parameters. My Saturday's 2.5 cents.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes! Excellent insight. That makes perfect sense. Convolving [1 1] (or anything) repeatably gives a Gaussian response which is related to two of my questions on "simplest way to implement a Gaussian FIR with no multipliers" and simple GMSK modulator implementation. Thanks for tying the bow on that knot!

Comment: +1 For "fred harris".

Comment: *"SuperKaiser"*  hmmmm.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson a complete subterfuge- don’t let anyone ever try to sell you one; I think the best time-BW for a discrete window is the DPSS of which Kaiser closely approximates, and for a window with infinite time support: a Gaussian—- hence the perceived “super-Kaiser” by convolving Kaisers and allowing the length to grow with each convolution. They all converge to a Gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an attacker with knowledge of the window and trying to focus noise spectrum so as to minimize your S/N, then a minimax solution, such as a Hamming window, might be the optimal counter.

Most noise tends not to be so purposefully malicious, rendering a minimax solution less optimal, at least statistically speaking.